# Confusion about plurality used in conventions in Caliburn.Micro

Tags: .net, caliburn.micro

I have used a Caliburn.Micro convention many places that says if you have a collection called `Apples`, you can add a property with the name `SelectedApple`, and this will be called whenever you select something in a ComboBox with the name `Apples`.

All of this is well. Now however, I have a list of different type of Statuses, but I cannot get this to work, maybe because Caliburn and I do not agree upon the proper plural form of the word status.

I have a collection called Statuses, and a property called SelectedStatus. The ComboBox is filled with all the statuses, but nothing happens when I select one of them in the list.

I have tried both Statuses, Status, Stati but to no avail.

Can anyone see why this isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

I'd never heard of Caliburn.Micro, but I found the documentation online and decided to search it. And [the answer is in there](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=All%20About%20Conventions&referringTitle=Documentation).

> Singularize – Turns a word from its plural form to its singular form. The default implementation is really basic and just strips the trailing ‘s’.

Comment: Hi Raymond. I forgot to say in the question that I actually tries using Statuss also just to be sure, but that didn't work out either...

Comment: Fortunately, Caliburn.Micro ships with source code, so you can just debug it.

Comment: Raymond - Probably the easiest solution if noone knows ;)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's expecting a property called **SelectedStatuse**, since it is just lopping off the trailing 's' in 'Statuses' and prepending the word 'Selected.'